# C# WMI remote program doesn't execute correctly

Tags: c#, wmi

I am trying to execute a program on a remote server using WMI.

When I execute my code, I can see the executable appear in the Process tab of Task Manager on the remote server, but it  never actually performs its function. There should be some files in a specific folder when it runs correctly but there are none when I run it from my program.

Also, I check the result reported back from WMI and I get a code of 0, which I believe indicates there were no errors.

I have posted the code below. If something in my code is not obviously wrong then I would appreciate advice on how to troubleshoot this as I am new to the WMI process.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Management;

namespace ExecuteNetworkResources
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var processToRun = new[] { "C:\\Program Files\\TestApplication\\mscombine.exe -c -cwa" };
            var connection = new ConnectionOptions();
            connection.Username = "domain\\user1;
            connection.Password = "password";
            var wmiScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2", "Server1"), connection);
            var wmiProcess = new ManagementClass(wmiScope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions());
            object result = wmiProcess.InvokeMethod("Create", processToRun);
            Console.WriteLine("Returned: " + result);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does the Remote server have `WMI enabled` can you do remote debugging..? if not then refactor the code to add some logging and some error trapping .. this should not take you that long to implement a few lines of code.. also contact the remote servers admin and see if they have enabled WMI could be a permissions issue outside of your local machine where it works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering this so I Can mark it as the answer for MethodMan. He was right, our server team says it is turned off.

Answer (score 1):

You are able to see the process in task manager in remote machine means WMI execution was successful. Now the issue that the files are not being created is because the remote process create method runs the process in **session 0**. Which is a non interactive desktop session.

This might be limiting the access/privilege of process to access the files system. Which is why you're not getting any error but the actions from the process are simply being ignored. You need to explicitly specify it in connection options to enable previleges:

```
        ConnectionOptions connection = new ConnectionOptions() {
            EnablePrivileges = true
        };
```

This will give the access to file system if user which is being used for connection have enough rights.

Comment: I will try this shortly and provide feedback.

Comment: WMI was turned off but I am up-voting this because I did not have this in my code and it is relevant to making a good conneciton. I don't understand how I can connect and see the application if WMI is off though.

Comment: You mentioned that it's invoking the process on remote machine so I assumed this is sample snippet from working code. One more thing I observed as missing here is 'wmiScope.Connect();' method call.